# grep a left parenthesis

Tags: linux, grep

I have the following content below in a file:

> text
>   (
>       gab "test"
>       set("TEST_SUB")
>       origin(354 504)
>       localize "T"
>   )

I have use vim **/text \n[\t]*.\n[\t]*** and the "text" word and the left parentheses was highlighted.

But when I use egrep 'text \n[\t]*.\n[\t]*' there is NO output. Just wondering how can I grep until the right parentheses.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `egrep` you can use `sed`.

`sed -n '/^text/,/^($/p' yourfile` will print all lines starting from where `text` is found until the `(` is found at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how long the sample is going to be, you can use the After flag, using `-AN` where N is the number of lines after the match you want to grab.

```
$grep -A7 "text" file.txt
text

(
      gab "test"
      set("TEST_SUB")
      origin(354 504)
      localize "T"
)
```

Comment: Also, you should know that a regular expression can not handle nested parentheses.

Comment: But, is there a way to put reg expression as the condition of SET may vary from case to case.

Comment: See Dan's answer, I believe sed or awk would be a better program to use than grep in this situation.